# Batteriser vs Joule Thief

Tags: prior-art-request, us20120121943

In reference to the patent for the "Batteriser": [US20120121943](https://www.google.com/patents/US20120121943), is this any different than the old Joule Thief designs that have been all over the web for years? Is it just the clever packaging that is different? If so, is clever packaging enough of a change to get a patent on an old technology?

Examples:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_thief
- http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-a-Joule-Thief/
- http://makezine.com/projects/joule-thief-battery-charger/

Comment: I can't say for sure on that, but there are also already numerous ICs available that do the same thing too.  The design of the physical product though is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I'm gathering, it's not; however, they are patenting their specific implementation of it - a thin sleeve that fits right over a battery and can still go into most sockets - and not the joule thief itself.